# Show image title on a seperate div upon hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery

I am new to jQuery and I am Trying to setup a gallery where when you hover over an image it shows the title attribute of that image on a div below and then on mouse out that title in the seperate div is hidden. Hope that makes sense!

What I have gotten so far is this

```
jQuery(".ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box img").each(function( index ) {
    var title = jQuery(this).attr( "title" );
    jQuery(".ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box img").on({
        mouseenter: function () {
           jQuery(".wpGallery").append(title);
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
           //stuff to do on mouse leave
        }
    });
});
```

In the above example the class " .ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box " is the div that holds the image ( There are multiple instances of this div one for each gallery image ). The " .wpGallery " is the class of the div to which the title should show up on upon hover.

Thanks so much in advance, Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `hover event` and append your title on `hover` then remove it in `hover out` like this https://jsfiddle.net/p74pL1d1/

```
jQuery(".ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box img").hover(function(){
  var title = jQuery(this).attr( "title" );
  jQuery(".wpGallery").append(title);
},function(){
  jQuery(".wpGallery").html('');
})
```